# Makefile - unterminated call to function `foreach': missing `)'. Stop

Tags: shell, build, foreach, makefile

This problem is driving me nuts! Here is my simple makefile:

```
SOURCES = a b c

$(foreach var,$(SOURCES),echo $(var);)

all:
    @echo done
```

With make 3.8, I get `Makefile:3: *** unterminated call to function 'foreach': missing ')'.  Stop.`

With make 3.81, I get `Makefile:3: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

BUT, if I put the foreach line within the 'all' target, it runs fine. Help!!

Answer (score 0):

That `foreach` will yield a bunch of `echo` commands.  You can't have those at the top level of a makefile.  Use [`$(info)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Make-Control-Functions.html) instead:

```
$(foreach var,$(SOURCES),$(info $(var)))
```

Example:

```
$ make
a
b
c
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up Make syntax and shell syntax.

If you put this statement outside a rule, it expands to

echo a; echo b; echo c;

which is nonsense as far as Make is concerned, since 1) `echo` is not a valid Make command, and 2) make will not accept the value of an expanded statement as a command (unless you use `eval`).

You should have:

1. Tried `echo a;`, and discovered that it didn't work outside a rule,

   found out about `info` and gotten the line to work,

   tried `foreach...` and discovered that it didn't work,

   found out about `eval`.